# jQuery reload table with new data based on data within loaded table

Tags: jquery, mysql, document-ready

I have a script doing a mysql query and populate a table using

```
  $('#results').html(returnData);
```

The mysql results contains data that should be clickable and reloaded into the same table (replacing the previous query).

Simplifying and boiling it down, the following code does not work:

```
   <head>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.a').click(function() {
            $('#results').html('THIS IS VALUE FROM LINK A <a href="#" class="b">B</a>');
        });

        $('.b').click(function() {
            $('#results').html('THIS IS VALUE FROM LINK B');
        });
    });​
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="results">THIS WILL BE REPLACED WITH VALUE FROM LINK A OR B</div><BR>
    <a href="#" class="a">LINK A</a><BR>
    <a href="#" class="b">LINK B</a>
```

If I click LINK A OR B the `div id="results"` is populated OK, but when I place the same link inside one of the `.html` results returned from click functions the link is not working and the div id"results" is not reloading itself.

So my questions are; why would that not work? and what would be the best way to reload the same table based on what you click inside the table that is already passed from `.html()`? I do not want to pass the clicked value on to a new page.

UPDATE:
This will work using .on()

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

$('body').on('click', '.a', function() { 
    $('#results').html('THIS IS VALUE FROM LINK A <a href="#" class="b">B</a>');
});

$('body').on('click', '.b', function() { 
    $('#results').html('THIS IS VALUE FROM LINK B');
});

});
</script>

</head>

<body>
<div id="results">THIS WILL BE REPLACED WITH VALUE FROM LINK A OR B</div><BR>
<a href="#" class="a">LINK A</a><BR>
<a href="#" class="b">LINK B</a>
```

Comment: Have you tried .on() method?

Comment: In other words, if you change `$('.a').click()` to `$('.a').on('click', function(){})`, things might begin to work like magic... :-)

Comment: I'm not sure if that will work, if you used .live() it would probably work, but that is deprecated functionality. You would need to use something like $('body').on('click', '#results .a', function(){});

Comment: If you look at my other comment, you will see that you are using the wrong syntax. your usage of .on() is attaching a listener to the links that already exist in the DOM. you need to use the syntax I provided, the element you attach .on() to must be a PARENT of what you are trying to click on, due to how events propagate up the DOM tree ('body' is a common catch all parent)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To elaborate on Abhilash's comment, the reason your click event isn't firing is due to the event listener only being attached to elements which currently exist in the DOM at the time onReady is executed.

.live() was introduced in older versions of jQuery - now deprecated in favor of .on() - to combat this problem. It allows you to attach events to a static element like body, and when the click event propagates up to the body it checks the original target element which triggered the event against your .on() selector, if they match it executes the handler.

Comment: I tried with .on(), but I could not get it to work. Using .live() worked like i wanted, but if .live() is deprecated how can I achieve the same result as with .live() using .on()?

Comment: I see that you tried to simply plug and play `.live()` and `.on()`, which wont work. You need to use the syntax in the docs, like `$('body').on('click', '.a', function() { });`

Comment: Thank you! It now worked! I will update my question with the correct code.

Comment: As a side note, `.live()` basically does what that code I posted does (propagates up to the body). The benefit of `.on()` and why `.live()` was deprecated is because `.on()` allows you to specify a parent that is 'closer' to the target element, which will stop the event from bubbling further up the DOM tree.

Answer (score 0):

Try this ::

```
  $('#results').find('.a').click(function() {
        $('#results').html('THIS IS VALUE FROM LINK A <a href="#" class="b">B</a>');
    });

   $('#results').find('.b').click(function() {
        $('#results').html('THIS IS VALUE FROM LINK B');
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.a').live("click", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#results').html('THIS IS VALUE FROM LINK A <a href="#" class="b">B</a>');
    });

    $('.b').live("click", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#results').html('THIS IS VALUE FROM LINK B');
});

});
</script>

<div id="results">THIS WILL BE REPLACED WITH VALUE FROM LINK A OR B</div><BR>
<a href="#" class="a">LINK A</a><BR>
<a href="#" class="b">LINK B</a>
```

Use live() to keep the event bound on newly created elements.

Comment: Thank you! Worked like a charm, but .live() is supposed to be deprecated in favor to .on(). I tried your code and replacing it with .on() but that did not work...